# Azure app service slot different value app setting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-webapps

I have a webapp with a slot. Both should have the app setting name DISABLE_CRON. The webapp (production slot) should have this setting set to false and the slot should have the setting set to true. I would like to do this with ARM-template. The webapp have many appsettings such as database name, database login username and password etc. I want all of those settings to be in a variable so I don't have to write them one time for the webapp and one time for the slot. Basically I just want to change the value to true on the slot and keep all other settings the same.

```
"variables": {
    "appName": "[concat(parameters('applicationName'),'-',parameters('environment'),'-app')]",
    "hostingPlanName": "[concat(parameters('applicationName'),'-',parameters('environment'),'-plan')]",
    "dbserverName": "[concat('onlinecampaignsites-',parameters('environment'),'-dbs-01')]",
    "connectionString": "[concat('Database=', parameters('applicationName'), ';Data Source=', concat('onlinecampaignsites-',parameters('environment'),'-dbs-01'),'.mysql.database.azure.com;User Id=',parameters('administratorLogin'),'@',concat('onlinecampaignsites-',parameters('environment'),'-dbs-01'),';Password=',parameters('administratorLoginPassword'))]",
    "appInsightsName": "[concat(parameters('applicationName'),'-',parameters('environment'),'-appIn')]",
    "databaseName": "[parameters('applicationName')]",
    "storageName": "[concat(parameters('applicationName'),parameters('environment'),'stg')]",
    "serverFarmResourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().name]",
    "subscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
    "containerName01": "[concat(parameters('applicationName'),'-',parameters('environment'),'-uploads')]",
    "staging": "staging",
    "appsettings": {
        "DISABLE_CRON": "false",
        "HEJSAN": "Den vann den"
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[variables('appname')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('hostingPlanName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    {
                        "name": "DISABLE_CRON",
                        "value": "true"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "hostNameSslStates":"[concat('{\"name\": \"',parameters('customDomain'),'\", \"sslState\": \"Disabled\", \"virtualIP\": null, \"thumbprint\": null, \"toUpdate\": null,\"hostType\": \"Standard\"}')]",
            "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', variables('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', variables('serverFarmResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
            "hostingEnvironment": "",
            "httpsOnly": true
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                "name": "slotconfignames",
                "type": "config",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('appName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "appSettingNames": [ "DISABLE_CRON" ]
                }
            },
            {
                "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                "type": "config",
                "name": "appsettings",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('appName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": "[variables('appsettings')]"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
        "name": "[concat(variables('appName'), '/', variables('staging'))]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('appName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('hostingPlanName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {},
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                "type": "config",
                "name": "appsettings",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', variables('appName'), variables('staging'))]"
                ],
                "properties": "[variables('appsettings')]"
            }
        ]
    },
```

In the ARM-template example there are two appsettings. It does not work to set the DISABLE_CRON to true, I just wanted to show that with this example.

Comment: Some configuration elements follow the content across a swap (not slot specific) while other configuration elements stay in the same slot after a swap (slot specific). App settings can be configured to stick to a slot.
If your requirement fits, to configure an app setting or connection string to stick to a specific slot (not swapped), navigate to the Application settings page for that slot, then select the Slot Setting box for the configuration elements that should stick to the slot. Kindly see if this helps your scenario.

Comment: In the portal I can do it, no problem. I am looking to do this in ARM-template.